# Is there a way to persist PlatformEvents that are sent during tests?

Tags: apex, unit-test, platform-event

**My question is:**
Is there a way to persist PlatformEvents that are sent during tests?

**What I want to achieve:**
I would like to log some warnings during the tests, which I could read later.

Answer (score 2):

No. Absolutely nothing aside from a debug log and test metrics (success/fail/code coverage) will persist beyond the scope of a unit test, including any DML operations, events, emails, scheduled jobs, etc. Your only choices are either cause an assertion to cause the test to fail (e.g. if you're concerned about governor limits, you can force a failed test), or you'll have to read the debug logs.